# Why is FormData so secretive/private?

Tags: javascript

Once I create FormData

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("hash", this.S.Storage.get('h_token'));
```

I can not stringify it:

```
JSON.stringify(form) // returns "{}"
```

I can't loop through it:

```
_.each(form, function(val){
    // nope
})
```

and I can't log it to the console ( w/ any useful results ).

```
console.log(form);
```

I have yet to encounter such a secretive type in JavaScript.

Comment: It's only meant for you to send data with XHRs, it seems it should have a way to inspect it, but there isn't... So the solution is... don't use `FormData` for anything besides sending XHRs, and do any checking of values before creating the `FormData` instance

Comment: well, yea, it is key based, so why can't I loop through it using `for in` is there a quick way to check the enumerable property?

Comment: Because it's implemented privately, they don't want to give you access to the internals, you're trying to use it for something that it's not intended...

Comment: I want to inspect it, not modify it, there is nothing wrong with that, except that I can't do it.

Comment: You're complaining about something you can't do anything about. May you learn to accept the things you can't change :) I suggested a way around it, don't pass around `FormData` See my answer

Comment: Just making a point.  No complaints.  I was planning on building a wrapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's so secretive because it's only intended to be used to pass data to an AJAX request and saves you from having to encode your data in 'multipart/form-data' on your own, as is done when you submit a form regularly. Therefore you should only use it at the last moment when you send the AJAX request, not pass it around to other functions.

Do if you need access to the same data anywhwere else, you could just pass around a simple JS object and write a simple helper like:

```
function createFormData(myData) {
   // It could also take an existing form for some values from the user
   var formData = new FormData(/** FormElement form */);
   for  (var key in myData) {
      formData.append(key, myData[key]);
   }
   return formData;
}

sendMyInfo: function(params)
  // Add some data to the default params
  params.hash = this.S.Storage.get('h_token'));
  params.cacheBuster = (new Date()).valueOf();

  // Inspect it
  console.log(myData);

  // Wherever you actually need FormData, create it for that purpose only....
  var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  oReq.open("POST", "stash.php", true);
  oReq.send(createFormData(myData));
};
```

Comment: You to have to form encode the contents of myData, the API doesn't say you can just pass a plain object to `FormData`. I think the point is that you should really only use FormData to pass data to the `XHR.send()`

Answer (score 3):

> I can not stringify it

Because it's a "host object" (provided by the host environment, the browser), and host objects cannot be stringified.

> I can't loop through it

This probably means it has no enumerable properties.

> and I can't log it to the console ( w/ any useful results ).

Actually console.log shows the only method defined in the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#formdata), `.append`.

**Why no enumerable properties**? I don't know, but considering you are responsible for populating the FormData, you're supposed to know its contents beforehand, don't you?

Comment: the properties should be enumerable and readable.  Exactly, if I populate it , I should have access to read it whenever I want.